# clang_complete and iOS

Tags: vim, clang, clang-complete

I recently found out about clang_complete and thought I'd give it a try in MacVim. I'm doing iOS dev and at the beginning I got the UIKit/UIKit.h file not found error like others have experienced.

I'm using Xcode 4.2 with the iOS 5 SDK. I've added the following to clang_user_options:

```
let g:clang_user_options='-fblocks -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000'
```

However now I'm getting the following errors whenever I trigger the autocompletion:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/../Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h|36 col 9 error| mac68k alignment pragma is not supported on this target
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFUtilities.h|14 col 39 error| expected function body after function declarator
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h|92 col 10 error| 'CoreFoundation/CFUserNotification.h' file not found
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Random guess: try adding "-m32".

Comment: Tried to add -m32 to the clang_user_options and it tells me unknown argument.

Comment: Oh... maybe try "-triple i386-apple-macosx10.7.0"?

Answer (score 0):

i had similar warning and error i added CFNetwork framework and warning resolved

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `-target i386-apple-macosx10.8.0` where 10.8.0 should be your Mac OS version.